# Magento 2: Changing layout XML with URL parameter

Tags: magento2, layout

Is it possible to control the layout using URL params? For example, I would like to be able to remove the sidebar block by adding `&sidebar=no` to the URL. It would be great if I can do this in the layout XML itself -- something like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <action method="remove" ifrequestparam="sidebar" condition="true">
            <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main"/>
        </action>
    </body>
</page>
```

I know this is not possible right now, but what is the next simplest method to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you get an idea from this, [we can able to remove block programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35867661/5528059).

so you can try in your **controller** like

```
if($this->request->getParam('sidebar')=='no')
{
    $layout = $this->getLayout();
    $block = $layout->getBlock('Block Name'); // block name
    $layout->unsetElement('Block Name');
}
```

I found only remove block programatically, may be chances is there to remove container but I'm not sure.